# how to resolve issue of overloaded operators/methods become ambiguous?

Tags: swift, oop

I am developing an application in swift. i have added two third party library [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) and [SQLite](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift), which are useful to me in my project.

These library integrated in my project, then after i am facing issue of conflict method of operator overloading because both library have overloaded same operator ( `<- operator` ).

Does any one have a solution, instead of removing one library from project.